# How does document.getSelection work under reactjs environment?

Tags: reactjs, web, electron, getselection

I was working on a electron-react project for `epub` file. Right now, I am planning to make the app capable of selecting text field and highlight it.

To achieve it, I was trying to use web's [Window.getSelection api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection). However, there are some really weird things come up like in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_oX45zjZ30&feature=youtu.be).

In short, I am unable to capture the Selection object. It seems like even if I log the Selection object, this object could somehow jump to something else. Also, I cannot even serialize the Selection object with `JSON.stringfy`. This is super surprising, and this is my first time seeing something like this (I will get empty object to stringfy the Selection object).

So how to use `Window.getSelection` properly under react-electron environment? Or this api will not work well for text content which is generated by react's dangerouslySetInnerHTML?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `window.getSelection` api needs to `toString` the selected object.

```
const getSelectionHandler = () => {
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  console.log("Got selection", selection.toString());
};
```

Super simple textarea and button to get selection react demo

[image: Edit relaxed-germain-rpo7e]

Comment: Still similar issue, base on the log. `toString` can still capture the text content, but after `click` event happen, the selection object magically refer to the pop up span element.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow this comment. In case it doesn't make sense in the demo, "current selection ..." is what is currently selected (highlighted) in real time as you select and highlight different substrings, while "Got selection ..." is also what is currently selected/highlighted but using the global `window.getSelection` function. There is no popup, or span, or magic.

Comment: The major issue is that `window.getSelection` or `document.getSelection`'s result cannot be catch somehow magically.

Comment: @JiahuaZhang I still do not understand what your issue is. What are you trying to "catch"? The demo shows getting the current selection 2 different ways in react. If this answer is not sufficient then may I recommend you update your question to be explicit to what you are trying to do, what you've attempted so far, and what isn't working to your expectations?

Comment: I am trying to catch text selection of the dom, so then it is possible for my app to make certain selection got highlighted. However, the selection cannot be "catched". Like in the demo shown, after first selection (just select text, then the log would refer the current node), and I tried to store this initial Selection object. However, after I clicked the panel (planning to apply different style in future), then the "stored Selection object" changed to the panel element. That's what I mean the Selection object cannot be catched.

Answer (score 1):

this solution might help someone, catch last selection

```
const selection = useRef('');
        
const handleSelection = () => {
  const text = document.getSelection().toString();
  if (text) {
    selection.current = text;
  }
 }
    
 useEffect(() => {
   document.addEventListener('selectionchange', handleSelection);
   return () => {
     document.removeEventListener('selectionchange', handleSelection);
   };
  });
```